# not able to retrieve direct child elements using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have an html table like this

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="prdLi">
              <td rowspan="2" class="prdNo"><span>310.</span></td>
              <td colspan="2" class="prdDe" rowspan="2"><span>Pepsi</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="prdLi">
              <td class="prdAc"><span> 1.5L</span></td>
              <td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the table is saved as $html

I want to select the child elements of the class .prdLi

I tried like this:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.prdLi') as $foo){
   echo $foo;

}
```

the output that i get is  like this

```
<span>310.</span>
<span>Pepsi</span
.
.
.
```

but what i actually want to get is the code with the parent element td.like this:

```
<td rowspan="2" class="prdNo"><span>310.</span></td>
<td colspan="2" class="prdDe" rowspan="2"><span>Pepsi</span></td>
.
.
.
```

please help me

Comment: What parser are you using, i.e. what is the type of `$html`?

Comment: so you want an echo with that literal tags? inside of the node values?

Comment: @Ghost i want the echo to contain the <td> parent tags

Comment: @andy Im using Simple HTML DOM Parser

Comment: How is `$html` created?

Comment: can you explain what is the purpose this? you just want to echo it?

Comment: @andy it was obtained using the `find()` in Simple HTML Parser, from higher elements in the DOM

Comment: @Ghost no.  i wanted to make the selection of the child elements inside the class `prdLi` and then use those elements to further obtain the data inside the `td`tags with the class names. I need the class names  of `td` to select the data. but what im getting instead is the child elements of `td` as `<span>....</span>`

Comment: Could you provide the script itself?

Comment: What if you try to output `echo $foo->outerHTML;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Simple HTML DOM Parser supports CSS like selectors, you can use `'tr.prdLi td'` to specify all `td` elements which are children of `tr` with class `prdLi`. The following should provide what you are looking for:

```
$htmlstr = <<<EOD
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="prdLi">
              <td rowspan="2" class="prdNo"><span>310.</span></td>
              <td colspan="2" class="prdDe" rowspan="2"><span>Pepsi</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="prdLi">
              <td class="prdAc"><span> 1.5L</span></td>
              <td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
EOD;

$html = str_get_html($htmlstr);
foreach ($html->find('tr.prdLi td') as $foo) {
    echo $foo . "\n";
}
```

Note that `find()` is called on the main `simple_html_dom`-element. In your example, the result was already limited by a previous `find()`.

Comment: but the output is as before, like this:
`<span>310.</span>
<span>Pepsi</span`

i'm trying to acheive this:
`<td rowspan="2" class="prdNo"><span>310.</span></td>  
 <td colspan="2" class="prdDe" rowspan="2"><span>Pepsi</span></td>`

Comment: I tested the above code with version 1.5 ($Rev: 210 $) of the parser and get exactly what you are looking for. Which code exactly are you using? What version or the parser?

Comment: im using the same version as yours `version 1.5 ($Rev: 210 $)`

Answer (score 1):

What andy says is correct, but the css for direct child is `> *`, therefore:

```
foreach($html->find('tr.prdLi > *') as $foo){
   echo $foo . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Simple HTML DOM does not support child selectors.

Comment: For full css3 support switch to [this](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom)